# is there a shift operation in R?

Tags: r

in c++ there is shift operartion

```
 >> right shift
 << left shift
```

this is consider to be very fast.
I tried to apply the same in R but it seems to be wrong.

Is there a similar operation in R that is as fast as this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: A more constructive comment: `??` is really quite helpful. If you type `?? "shift"` or `?? "bitwise"` in the R console you are quickly lead to the help page for R's bitwise operators, including the shift operators.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `bitwShiftL` and `bitwShiftR`:

```
bitwShiftL(16, 2)
#[1] 64

bitwShiftR(16, 2)
#[1] 4
```

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e5b21d0397c607883ff25cca379687b86933d730/src/main/relop.c#L793-L839).   Judging by the amount of additional code in these functions, and the fact that `*` and `/` are primitives, is unlikely that these will be faster than dividing / multiplying by the equivalent power of two. On one of my VMs,

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    bitwShiftL(16, 2),
    16 * 4,
    times = 1000L
)
#Unit: nanoseconds
#              expr  min     lq     mean median   uq    max neval cld
# bitwShiftL(16, 2) 1167 1353.5 2336.779   1604 2067 117880  1000   b
#            16 * 4  210  251.0  564.528    347  470  51885  1000   a

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    bitwShiftR(16, 2),
    16 / 4,
    times = 1000L
)
# Unit: nanoseconds
#               expr  min     lq     mean median     uq   max neval cld
#  bitwShiftR(16, 2) 1161 1238.5 1635.131 1388.5 1688.5 39225  1000   b
#               16/4  210  240.0  323.787  280.0  334.0 14284  1000   a
```

---

I should also point out that trying to micro-optimize an interpreted language is probably a waste of time. If performance is such a big concern that you are willing to split hairs over a couple of clock cycles, just write your program in C or C++ in the first place.